# Why can't we set line-height less than 1 for span element?

Tags: html, css

If I increase the line-height of the span element's content then the space above and below each individual line increases. But if I decrease the line-height below 1 then nothing happens. Following is the code I am trying; I change the values in the inline style attribute of span

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p>
<span style="line-height: 0.1">
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
</span>


<span>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
</span>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You *can* set a smaller value than 1. But it will only have an effect if the line-height set on the containing block element is even smaller, because otherwise the strut will provide a minimum value for the line height.

Answer (score 14):

Line-height is a multiplier of its font-size. Suppose, if you have set font-size to `12px` then the line-height set to `1.5` is equal to `12*1.5=18px`.

And the fact about the line-height with block level element works as you expect but with the inline level elements the line-height cannot go below to its font-size. So, setting the line-height below the value of 1 is invalid as `0.5*12=6px` which is less than the font-size.

If you want to expect its line-height would work below its font-size then you need to explicitly set its style to the block level:

```
span{
  display: block;/*or inline-block*/
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: .5;/*equal to 8px*/
}
```

There's even more thing to know about line-height. Look it at [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading)

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element. The minimum height consists of a minimum height above the baseline and a minimum depth below it, exactly as if each line box starts with a zero-width inline box with the element's font and line height properties. We call that imaginary box a "strut."
>
> When an element contains text that is rendered in more than one font, user agents may determine the 'normal' 'line-height' value according to the largest font size.

To conclude:

In inline level elements the height cannot be set like that the line-height cannot go below its height.

Comment: "_but with the inline level elements the line-height cannot exceed to its font-size_"-- It can. If I set line-height:2 in span element the line height increases.

Comment: sorry the term I used was wrong.Corrected- `exceed` word with `below`. Thanks for catch.

Comment: Yes, and you said for inline elements it cannot exceed the font-size.

Comment: @user31782 I was trying to say below but mistakenly wrote exceed that I already corrected.

Comment: What is _line boxes_ and _baseline_?

Comment: @user31782 - Most of the concepts in CSS for normal flow come from [Movable Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movable_type). A line box is the area in which one line of text characters is placed. Its height, that is the actual line height, is the smallest height that allows all the characters and the strut (see quote above) to be contained, allowing for different font sizes, leading, and vertical alignments. The baseline is a vertical position on the font used for vertical alignment, splitting each character into an ascender (above the baseline) and a descender (below the baseline).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a span you need to set `display: block`

```
<span style="line-height: 50%; display: block;">
  This is Sparta!<br>
  This is Sparta!<br>
  This is Sparta!<br>
</span>
```

Comment: But it works with span for values of `line-height>1`. You can try it yourself.

Comment: I guess there is something to do with the `span` being an inline element.

Comment: If it works with span for values of line-height>1 then why doesn't it work for line-height<1 with span?

Comment: was banging my head against the wall for a week trying to figure this out. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding the paragraphs to a `<span>` element? I would do it as follows. That way you will be able to control all the paragraph tags

```css
p{line-height:1px;}
```

```html
<p>

This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
<p>This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<p>
<p>This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<p>
<p>This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<p>
<p>This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<p>
```

Comment: No I want to know only about `span` element.

Comment: then you have 3 options, 1.use a div instead of a span, 2.add “display: block” to force it to act like a block element, or 3.add “display: inline-block” to make it act like an block element

Comment: But then why does it work with span for values of `line-height>1`?

Comment: if you add 'display:block' then the item reads the values less then 1. This is because the effect of line-height is only on inline elements. When line-height is applied to block, inline-block or any other type of element that is not inline, the effects are on the inline descendant elements only.

Comment: Ok that was about how it works on block-level elements. But why doesn't it work with inline elements like span when we set line-height<1?

Comment: Inline elements don't conform to properties such as line-height; they take on the line height of the nearest block parent. Because they inherit these values they take it as a whole number and this is why it cannot read <1

Comment: But when we change line-height to a value>1 then why doesn't it inherit the same whole number any longer? If line-height:2 can override the inherited property then why can't line-height:0.5 override the same?

Comment: I would suggest reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Comment: I did read that. But that is above my level at present. They use the terminology I am not familiar with, e.g. _line boxes, non-replaced inline elements, Canonical order_ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 p{line-height:1px;}
```

You can use pixels (px) in line height

Comment: Why don't you guys understand? I know it will work for **block-level** elements. I am asking if it works with span for values of line-height>1 then why it doesn't work for line-height<1?

Comment: @user31782, Your question doesn't say, "I know block level elements will achieve this", you phrased your question in a way that it sounds like your simply looking for a solution!

Answer (score 1):

`<span>`'s are inline elements, so `line-height` won't apply in the way you want it to. Try making the span in question a block level element and see what happens, here's an example:

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  line-height: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
</span>

<span>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
This is a paragraph with a standard line-height.<br>
</span>
```

Comment: But then why does it work with span for values of line-height>1?

Comment: @user31782, I'm not completely sure to be honest, I haven't looked into it a great deal but as you can see, line-height behaves differently for inline and block level elements.

Answer (score 0):

Inline-level elements are strongly related to their parents.
But you can try to set line-height directly to this inline-element's block-level parent.

```
.text-wrapper {
  line-height: 0.2;
}
.text {
  line-height: 0.2;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nickensoul/pen/dKPeGm).
Looks like this trick works.